# How to make registration-free interface call from a DLL to a COM object implemented in EXE of the same process?

Tags: com, reg-free

It is now well known how to make interface call to a DLL-implemented COM object in the registration-free environment. The question is the opposite:

How to make interface call from a DLL to a COM object implemented in EXE? Which manifests and which manifest sections should be used?

EDIT: May be it was not quite clear, but I meant **in-process** call. I want to call an object in the same process, but implemented in EXE rather than in DLL.

EDIT2: OK, I see things goes complicated, so I must explain the original problem. A **C++** application implements IApplication interface and keeps pointer to it as a member. This member is returned by a public method accessible from anywhere by means of AfxGetApp().

There is also a mechanism allowing any customer to add his own **C#** "plugin" DLLs to our application. For such DLLs the IApplication interface is a key access point to the application's features. But these DLLs have no access to the main application's object.

To solve the problem, I added an auxiliary "ICreateApplication" object, which returns the original IApplication pointer. Any "plugin" DLL may create this auxiliary object and obtain from it the required interface. I implemented this object in some arbitrarily chosen DLL, and equipped it with necessary manifests.

This solution works well, but this "arbitrary choice" bothers me. I wonder, is there a possibility to implement "ICreateApplication" in the application object?

Comment: Start reading at [Not every component is a suitable candidate](https://web.archive.org/web/20080915135918/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx)

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm aware about problems with "EXE" COM servers, but my question was about in-process object. Please see the corrected question.

Comment: Your question title sucks serious rocks.  It is also completely unclear why the server is not allowed to know anything about the DLL.  It loads it so it better know *something* about it.  Like an entrypoint to which it can pass an interface pointer so there is no need at all to let COM find the server back..

Comment: @HansPassant, You are right, but it was not simple to find a correct "abstract" wording without explaining the whole problem. Please see the second EDIT.